# paypal payment not going through with any of the options

Tags: paypal, vbscript, asp-classic, express-checkout

Using ASP Classic

Paypal LIVE Express checkout

It shows the Payment Amount at the checkout, but the payment doesn't go through.  The payment doesn't even leave customer's account. I have tried using my wife's paypal account to complete the checkout.

I am only using paypal checkout system and have added all the API information in expresscheckout.asp and paypalfunctions.asp

I have also tried adding these API options too, but still wouldnt work

L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEm

L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NUMBERm

L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMTm

L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_QTYm

Any help would be great.... tks

Comment: most likely, you are not caling DoExpressCheckout API call

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply,
its all there in the file paypalfunctions.asp 
Set Get ... DoExpressCheckoutPayment,

Comment: well yea, i just found out that i need to call DoExpresscheckoutPayment

After PAY NOW (on Paypal website), it redirects to my website page. How should call DoExpressCheckoutPayment.... do i need to add some code in that redirect page?  Can you please help me out with this.

Comment: Call SetExpressCheckout to get your token and redirect to PayPal.  That's where you also specify your ReturnURL.  When the continue/pay button is clicked at PayPal they send the user back to your ReturnURL.  There is where you can call GetExpressCheckoutDetails (if necessary) and then finalize everything with DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

Comment: tks... can you please help me how to call DoExpressCheckoutPayment in the returnurl.